# Using Permissions bukkit. How do I add a player through chat command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I think it's a bit annoying to open up `config.yml` for permissions every time I want to add someone to the server. As default, no one has permissions to do anything, they need to be in the `user` group. Is there a way to do this through the in game console?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command to set a player's group with PermissionsBukkit:

```
/permissions player setgroup <player> <group>
```

So, this would set a player named Bob to the 'user' group:

```
/permissions player setgroup Bob user
```

Just make sure that you have the `permissions.player.setgroup` permission node set to true. You can also just use `permissions.player.*` or just `permissions.*` to get that permission as well.

Comment: Maybe merge the two answers to create a 2 way solution?

Answer (score 0):

I use a plugin called setrank to achieve this. There are two versions, one for PEX here http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/setrankpex/

and one for bukkitperms here
http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/setrankpb/

(I think you want the second one)

It's quite easy to set up and use and if you want to let users buy ranks it can be configured (they use the /promo command)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use `/permissions player setgroup`, but it didn't work on my server.  I suggest using `/promote <player>` for smaller servers. I also had to remove my whitelist/blacklist to make this plugin work.